# how to list all objects releated to a model via another model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails project with many users.
Each **user** has_many **photos**.
Each **photo** has_many **comments**.

I want to get a `@usercomments` in `user_controller` which contains list of all comments associated with that user.
I tried:

```
@usercomments = @user.photo.each.comments.where( accepted: false )
```

Didnt work.
How can i do this?
I couldn't find any related answers, maybe i am not wording it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add a has_many relationship for User model, sth like

```
has_many :associated_comments, class_name: Comment, through: Photo,
  foreign_key: ****, primary_key: ****
```

It will be more clear, if you provide your User/Photo/Comment table fields

Comment: comments model I am using as through, photos has_many comments, photos has_many likers, through comments, class : "User"...

Comment: @SiDDevesh provide your schema for these models please

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem with my models. It was not only the relationship  (has_many /belongs_to), that was set in the models, it was because I had no foreign key in the model with the "belongs_to" relation. You should have a look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can add this in your user model.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :photos
has_many :comments
has_many :photo_comments, through: :photos, class_name: "Comment"
```

**photo.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

You can get all comments by:

```
@user.comments
```

You can get user post comment by:

```
@user.photo_comments
```

I hope this help you.